# Call a Ruby method explicitly using the default for a parameter

Tags: ruby

An unfortunately large number of methods are written in the following form:

```
def my_method(foo = {}, bar = {})
  # Do stuff with foo and bar
end
```

While I appreciate not having to write `my_method({}, {})` everywhere I reference the method, using something other than the default for the second parameter makes me use something other than the default for the first parameter too - `my_method({}, foo: 'bar')`.

**Is there a way to tell Ruby to use the default for a parameter when other, later parameters need to use something other than the default?** I'm hoping for something in the form of `my_method(__default__, foo: 'bar')`, but would welcome any other solutions that address the core of this problem.

This would be particularly useful when APIs undergo minor (but significant) changes. It can lead to hard to find bugs occasionally:

```
# Original method
def foo(value = 'true', options = {})
  # ...
end

# Defaults are updated slightly in a new version of the library
def foo(value = true, options = {})
  # ...
end

# My code might break in an unexpected way now
foo('true', bar: 'baz')
```

Comment: It's important to note that these method definitions are often in 3rd party gems or libraries. If I controlled the source, there are plenty of ways to solve this on the method definition side. I'm looking for solutions that solve this when **calling** the method.

Comment: If someone changed the signature like this, they're being jerks. There's not much you can do but try and supply values valid in both cases.

Comment: @tadman Some of them certainly are, especially when these changes are in a point release. Others are solving real problems with their changes, possibly even in a major gem release. We can't expect other developers to live with bad method signatures they wrote once long ago just so they don't break our code. Good test coverage certainly mitigates the risk of these types of changes, but the less breakage I have when I do a `bundle update` the better.

Answer (score 7):

This is the problem which keyword arguments (new to ruby 2) were made to solve (provided that you control the method definition).

```
def foo(a: {}, b: {})
  "a: #{a}, b: #{b}"
end

foo # => "a: {}, b: {}"
foo(a: 1, b: 2) # => "a: 1, b: 2"
foo(a: 3) # => "a: 3, b: {}"
foo(b: 4) # => "a: {}, b: 4"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just refactor the code to something like this, so it gets assigned to the default value only if the named parameter isn't provided a value.

```
def my_method(foo, bar)
  foo ||= {}; bar ||= {};
  #=> Do something with foo and bar now.
end
```

What `||=` operator does is, it assigns the value on the right to the variable on the left if the variable isn't initialized or has `nil` value.

You can now call it like this

```
my_method(nil, "I'm bar");
```

If by any chance, you *want* to pass `nil` as a value, then this will fail. Sergio Tulentsev's answer is the way to go. I'd have suggested the same had I known it.

Comment: Creating a variable like `_default_` is really over the top here.

Comment: What if someone _wanted_ to pass nil as a value?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I didn't' think of it. Providing clarification

Answer (score 1):

You could set defaults to nil then handle the actual defaulting of values within the body of the method. ie.,

```
def my_method(first=nil, second=nil)
  first_value  = first || 1
  second_value = second || 2
end
```

This allows you to pass 'nil' when you want that value to be its default. For example,

```
my_method(nil, 'second')
```

Now 'first_value' is 1 and second_value is 'second'.

edit: though 'nil' is really non-descriptive of the action of making the method use its default value. Consider:

```
def my_method(first=:default, second=:default)
  first_value = (first == :default ? 1 : first)
 second_value = (second== :default ? 2 : second)
end
```

Then you can do:

```
my_method(:default, 'second')
```

(but really Sergio's answer is the best =) )